# iOS how to create a UIView border with label on top of that

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer

[image]

I have to add label on top of UIView border, how do I achieve that using beizer path by drawing only part of the border on view

Comment: Make custom view. Add label on top of view and constraint it accordingly.

Comment: you can achieve this by creating custom textField, adding border and label on top left...

Answer (score 2):

This can be realized by implementing a `BorderLabelView` where a `contentView` and a `label` is added. To the `contentView` a `textField` is added which is positioned vertically centered to its parent.

The `label` is positioned relatively to the top of the parent but moved up by a negative constant value.

An extra `contentView` is used (instead of the `BorderLabelView` itself) to set the border with rounded corners, so that `masksToBounds` can be set without masking the part of the label that sticks up a little bit.

For the label some leading and trailing space is needed. That is why UILabel is subclassed so that `intrinsicContentSize` can be reset.

This is a working example implementation:

```
import UIKit

class PaddedLabel: UILabel {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width + 20, height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height)
    }
}

class BorderLabelView: UIView {
    convenience init(labelName: String, textContent: String) {
        self.init()

        let contentView = UIView()

        contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true;

        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.textColor = .black
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22.0)
        textField.text = textContent

        contentView.addSubview(textField)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
        textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        addSubview(contentView)

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true

        let label = PaddedLabel()
        label.text = labelName
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        label.textAlignment = .center

        addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    }
}
```

The view can be used by calling the initializer

```
BorderLabelView(labelName: "User name", textContent: "Sanjay SK")
```

This is an example implementation for a UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class BorderLabelController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let borderLabelView = BorderLabelView(labelName: "User name", textContent: "Sanjay SK")
        view.addSubview(borderLabelView)

        borderLabelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        borderLabelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        borderLabelView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

        borderLabelView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        borderLabelView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a border and rounded `UIView`.. Inside that view you can add label or `UITextField` whose text is "Sanjay SK" with respect to given sample image

Give that view border color , border width and corer radious.. then take a `UILabel` with background color white and add it over that bordered `UIView` ... will give you same look and feel ... hope it will help you